# Unable to store complex json document in mongodb

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to create a document in mongo but facing some errors may due to incorrect mongodb schema. Please correct me . Thanks in advance.

**MongoDB Schema**

```
const createMatchSchema = new Schema({
  match_key : {
    type : String,
    required : true
  },
  match_status : {
    type : String,
    required : true
  },
  players : [{
      fullname : String,
      innings : [{
          fielding : {
            catches : Number,
            runouts : Number,
            stumbeds : Number
          },
          batting : {
            dots : Number,
            sixes : Number,
            runs : Number,
            balls : Number,
            fours : Number,
            strike_rate : Schema.Types.Decimal128,
            dismissed : Boolean
          },
          bowling : {
            dots: Number,
            runs: Number,
            balls: Number,
            maiden_overs: Number,
            wickets: Number,
            extras: Number,
            overs: String,
            economy: Number
          }
        }],
      identified_roles : {
        keeper : { type : Boolean, default: false },
        bowler : { type : Boolean, default: false },
        batsman : { type : Boolean, default: false }
      }
  }],
  createdOn : {
    type : String,
    default : moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY-hh-mm-ss')
  }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model("MatchData", createMatchSchema, 'matchDataCollection');
```

**JSON Data**

```
{
"match_key": "match_key",
"match_status": "completed",
"players": [{
    "fullname": "Dwayne Bravo",
    "innings": [{
        "fielding": {},
        "bowling": {
            "dots": 6,
            "runs": 36,
            "balls": 24,
            "maiden_overs": 0,
            "wickets": 2,
            "extras": 2,
            "overs": "4.0",
            "economy": 9
        },
        "batting": {
            "dots": 1,
            "sixes": 1,
            "runs": 15,
            "balls": 9,
            "fours": 0,
            "strike_rate": 166.67,
            "dismissed": false
        }
    }],
    "identified_roles": {
        "keeper": false,
        "bowler": true,
        "batsman": true
    }
}]
```

}

**Query**

```
dd.findOneAndUpdate({'match_key':'aa'},JSONData,{upsert:true},function(err,resp){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      res.json({'s':100});
    }
    else{
      res.json(resp);
    }
  });
```

Facing some error ....

```
{ CastError: Cast to embedded failed for value "{ identified_roles: { batsman: true, bowler: true, keeper: false },\n  innings: [ { batting: [Object], bowling: [Object], fielding: {} } ],\n  fullname: \'Dwayne Bravo\' }" at path "players"
    at new CastError (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\cast.js:27:11)
    at DocumentArray.cast (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\documentarray.js:340:19)
    at castUpdateVal (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:313:22)
    at walkUpdatePath (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:229:22)
    at castUpdate (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:72:18)
    at model.Query._castUpdate (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3181:10)
    at castDoc (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3207:18)
    at model.Query.Query._findAndModify (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2327:19)
    at model.Query.Query._findOneAndUpdate (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2162:8)
    at E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\kareem\index.js:250:8
    at E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\kareem\index.js:23:7
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
  message: 'Cast to embedded failed for value "{ identified_roles: { batsman: true, bowler: true, keeper: false },\\n  innings: [ { batting: [Object], bowling: [Object], fielding: {} } ],\\n  fullname: \\\'Dwayne Bravo\\\' }" at path "players"',
  name: 'CastError',
  stringValue: '"{ identified_roles: { batsman: true, bowler: true, keeper: false },\\n  innings: [ { batting: [Object], bowling: [Object], fielding: {} } ],\\n  fullname: \\\'Dwayne Bravo\\\' }"',
  kind: 'embedded',
  value: '{ identified_roles: { batsman: true, bowler: true, keeper: false },\n  innings: [ { batting: [Object], bowling: [Object], fielding: {} } ],\n  fullname: \'Dwayne Bravo\' }',
  path: 'players',
  reason:
   { CastError: Cast to Array failed for value "[ { batting:
     { dismissed: false,
       strike_rate: 166.67,
       fours: 0,
       balls: 9,
       runs: 15,
       sixes: 1,
       dots: 1 },
    bowling:
     { economy: 9,
       overs: '4.0',
       extras: 2,
       wickets: 2,
       maiden_overs: 0,
       balls: 24,
       runs: 36,
       dots: 6 },
    fielding: {} } ]" at path "innings"
    at new CastError (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\cast.js:27:11)
    at EmbeddedDocument.$set (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:773:7)
    at EmbeddedDocument._handleIndex (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:594:14)
    at EmbeddedDocument.$set (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:554:24)
    at EmbeddedDocument.Document (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:83:12)
    at EmbeddedDocument [as constructor] (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\embedded.js:31:12)
    at new EmbeddedDocument (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\documentarray.js:74:17)
    at DocumentArray.cast (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\documentarray.js:333:22)
    at castUpdateVal (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:313:22)
    at walkUpdatePath (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:229:22)
    at castUpdate (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:72:18)
    at model.Query._castUpdate (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3181:10)
    at castDoc (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3207:18)
    at model.Query.Query._findAndModify (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2327:19)
    at model.Query.Query._findOneAndUpdate (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2162:8)
    at E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\kareem\index.js:250:8
    at E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\kareem\index.js:23:7
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
     message: 'Cast to Array failed for value "[ { batting: \n     { dismissed: false,\n       strike_rate: 166.67,\n       fours: 0,\n       balls: 9,\n       runs: 15,\n       sixes: 1,\n       dots: 1 },\n    bowling: \n     { economy: 9,\n       overs: \'4.0\',\n       extras: 2,\n       wickets: 2,\n       maiden_overs: 0,\n       balls: 24,\n       runs: 36,\n       dots: 6 },\n    fielding: {} } ]" at path "innings"',
     name: 'CastError',
     stringValue: '"[ { batting: \n     { dismissed: false,\n       strike_rate: 166.67,\n       fours: 0,\n       balls: 9,\n       runs: 15,\n       sixes: 1,\n       dots: 1 },\n    bowling: \n     { economy: 9,\n       overs: \'4.0\',\n       extras: 2,\n       wickets: 2,\n       maiden_overs: 0,\n       balls: 24,\n       runs: 36,\n       dots: 6 },\n    fielding: {} } ]"',
     kind: 'Array',
     value: [ [Object] ],
     path: 'innings',
     reason:
      { CastError: Cast to embedded failed for value "{ batting: \n   { dismissed: false,\n     strike_rate: 166.67,\n     fours: 0,\n     balls: 9,\n     runs: 15,\n     sixes: 1,\n     dots: 1 },\n  bowling: \n   { economy: 9,\n     overs: \'4.0\',\n     extras: 2,\n     wickets: 2,\n     maiden_overs: 0,\n     balls: 24,\n     runs: 36,\n     dots: 6 },\n  fielding: {} }" at path "innings"
    at new CastError (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\cast.js:27:11)
    at DocumentArray.cast (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\documentarray.js:340:19)
    at DocumentArray.SchemaType.applySetters (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:705:12)
    at EmbeddedDocument.$set (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:764:18)
    at EmbeddedDocument._handleIndex (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:594:14)
    at EmbeddedDocument.$set (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:554:24)
    at EmbeddedDocument.Document (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:83:12)
    at EmbeddedDocument [as constructor] (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\embedded.js:31:12)
    at new EmbeddedDocument (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\documentarray.js:74:17)
    at DocumentArray.cast (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\documentarray.js:333:22)
    at castUpdateVal (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:313:22)
    at walkUpdatePath (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:229:22)
    at castUpdate (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\services\query\castUpdate.js:72:18)
    at model.Query._castUpdate (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3181:10)
    at castDoc (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3207:18)
    at model.Query.Query._findAndModify (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2327:19)
    at model.Query.Query._findOneAndUpdate (E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2162:8)
    at E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\kareem\index.js:250:8
    at E:\SportsWin\new-nodeserver\node_modules\kareem\index.js:23:7
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
        message: 'Cast to embedded failed for value "{ batting: \\n   { dismissed: false,\\n     strike_rate: 166.67,\\n     fours: 0,\\n     balls: 9,\\n     runs: 15,\\n     sixes: 1,\\n     dots: 1 },\\n  bowling: \\n   { economy: 9,\\n     overs: \\\'4.0\\\',\\n     extras: 2,\\n     wickets: 2,\\n     maiden_overs: 0,\\n     balls: 24,\\n     runs: 36,\\n     dots: 6 },\\n  fielding: {} }" at path "innings"',
        name: 'CastError',
        stringValue: '"{ batting: \\n   { dismissed: false,\\n     strike_rate: 166.67,\\n     fours: 0,\\n     balls: 9,\\n     runs: 15,\\n     sixes: 1,\\n     dots: 1 },\\n  bowling: \\n   { economy: 9,\\n     overs: \\\'4.0\\\',\\n     extras: 2,\\n     wickets: 2,\\n     maiden_overs: 0,\\n     balls: 24,\\n     runs: 36,\\n     dots: 6 },\\n  fielding: {} }"',
        kind: 'embedded',
        value: '{ batting: \n   { dismissed: false,\n     strike_rate: 166.67,\n     fours: 0,\n     balls: 9,\n     runs: 15,\n     sixes: 1,\n     dots: 1 },\n  bowling: \n   { economy: 9,\n     overs: \'4.0\',\n     extras: 2,\n     wickets: 2,\n     maiden_overs: 0,\n     balls: 24,\n     runs: 36,\n     dots: 6 },\n  fielding: {} }',
        path: 'innings',
        reason: [MongooseError] } } }
```

Please help me ....

Comment: The problem is the `Schema.Types.Decimal128`. Mongoose is expecting the data to "cast" to be a "string" i.e `"strike_rate": "166.67"`. You probably don't understand that `Number` in mongoose is the same as `Double` as a BSON type, so `166.67` is perfectly okay for `Number`. Either change the type or make the really long floating point numbers in your JSON "strings" instead. But chances are your source data is rounded anyway, so just make them `Number` in the schema.

Comment: I'm also taking a guess that this is your first "outing" with MongoDB in general. Whilst it might have seemed intuitive to you, I would strongly advise against using such a deeply nested schema with "arrays within arrays". This is not a very good pattern, as it is basically impossible to atomically update without MongoDB 3.6 features, and even with them it's still a real pain to query. You will be far better off reading up on the subject and then actually making some core observations about what data you actually need to present in a page for your application.

Comment: thank you so much guys... your valuable comments have solved my problem.